# What is the elegant way to delete tmpfile created by boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, raii

I had a code snippet

```cpp
        if (!boost::filesystem::exists(tempDir)) {
            boost::filesystem::create_directories(tempDir);
        }
        auto path = tempDir / boost::filesystem::unique_path("gfbfv1-%%%%-old");
        do_something_maythrow(path);
        remove(path);
```

How can I ensure that path is always deleted even in case of `do_something_maythrow` throwing?

Should I write a `FileDeleter` which takes a path and remove that path on destructor which utilize the so-called `RAII` concept or is there an existing solution?

Comment: Also consider https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpfile - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1457524c7eba966

Comment: @sehe I am pretty new to c++, this “FILE*” return type seems too hard to cooperate with other interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I write a FileDeleter which takes a path and remove that path on destructor which utilize the so-called RAII concept

This is a fairly reasonable solution. Be careful to take care of any exceptions that the deletion may raise because you wouldn't want to throw from a destructor, especially from one that is being executed because of a thrown exception.

However, if this is not a commonly needed structure, and therefore there isn't a need for a reusable solution, then a simple ad-hoc alternative is to use [ScopeExit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) also known as Scope Guard.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, I used the keyword `defer` and failed to find this library.

Comment: That's because it doesn't defer things. It makes them  run at a deterministic time.

Comment: @sehe It's actually very alike to the concept `defer` in golang and Swift.